# Cannot add element after element removed in same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen remove and add work `onclick`. But never within a single function.

I simply want a function that, when called, will remove an element from the DOM, and re-add the element with a delay. -- so the question is, can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

I can remove elements, I can get alerts when they are removed. I can add elements with a delay and they appear — no problem.

I can make each function separately and they work (though calling one from the other doesn’t). But the minute I try to replace an `alert` with a delay and an add, nothing happens. No errors. Just nothing.

I can’t run separate functions, I need the add to happen directly after the remove. I need the function to run over and over and over again when called, without refreshing the page.

Toggling the `display` property is not an option!

```
$("#captcha").on("remove", function () {
    alert("Element was removed"); //works perfectly
    $("#contain").delay(10000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).add('<iframe id="captcha" class="captcha" src="mypage.php"></iframe>');
    });  // doesn't work inside this function but works perfectly outside this function
});

function RemoveDiv() {
    var d = $("#captcha");
    d.remove();
}
RemoveDiv();
```

Equally I have tried to create a function AddDiv() and add then call AddDiv(); from inside RemoveDiv();

**Updates:**

```
function RemoveDiv() {
    $('#captcha').remove();
    $('#contain').append('<iframe id="captcha" class="captcha" src="/includes/captcha.php" style="style=border:0; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 100; width: 430px; height:75px;left: 20px; top: 20px; border:none;"></iframe>').delay(10000).queue(function (next) {
        $('#contain').append('<iframe id="captcha" class="captcha" src="/includes/captcha.php" style="style=border:0; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 100; width: 430px; height:75px;left: 20px; top: 20px; border:none;"></iframe>');
        next();
    });
}
```

The append function works outside of the RemoveDiv function and creates a delay, if I use a standard append it works inside the RemoveDiv function, but it won't work with a delay. So how do I join these two things so the delay works inside the RemoveDiv function?

Comment: Adding an element *with a delay* introduces an asynchronous aspect to your function, which means the element would be added to the DOM *after* the `add()` function exits - is that part of your problem? Please [edit] your question to show an example of the code you've tried, or at least an example of the remove and add functions that you say work in isolation. What's the point of removing and re-adding an element within the same function? (Thousands, plural, "literally"? Really?)

Comment: You haven't asked a question, you should at least post a sample of what you tried and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes literally, I added code.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I added the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Xufox I added code.

Comment: Your code seems overly complicated, try using this as a base: https://jsfiddle.net/nf942cez/

Comment: What is the `this` value on the line with `.add()`? It won't be the `#captcha` element, if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: Does this do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/0qk4z4vg/

Comment: @nnnnnn As I suggested, I have tried thousands of variations, using #contain in place of this has no effect.

Even, as I stated already, that js fiddle uses onclick, the minute I try it as a function, it fails. https://jsfiddle.net/nf942cez/1/

Comment: That fiddle fails because you have a syntax error. Look at the console.

Comment: Did you look at *my* fiddle? It has a function that can be called without a click, and here's an update that does so: https://jsfiddle.net/0qk4z4vg/1/ (Note also that a click handler *is* a function...)

Comment: okay I don't know how else to possibly explain this. I need a function I can  CALL.... not one that loops a few hundred times. I need to be able to call the function.... function(); from elsewhere and have it run each time it is called.

Comment: can someone at least explain to me why it is a function cannot be written that will both remove, and then readd, when the function is called?

Comment: We can't explain to you why such a function can't be written because in fact **it *can* be written**, and that's what @EvanTrimboli and I have done. A function you can call is what I put in my fiddle - it may not be quite what you want but it clearly shows that a single, named function can both remove and then re-add the same element.

Comment: It already is a callable function. I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings about how functions work in JS. Here is the same thing as a named function: https://jsfiddle.net/nf942cez/3/

Comment: No actually it can;t be done, what Even is showing me is as close as it gets, but append is not add, add is an element that works with effects and append is not, and therefore append cannot be used with .delay and thus -both my questions stand. Why cannot add not be used with remove in the same function.

Comment: jQuery's `.add()` method does *not* add elements to the DOM. It is not the opposite of the `.remove()` method.

Comment: Your question asks: "I simply want a function that, when called, will remove an element from the DOM, and re-add the element with a delay." I showed you how to do that. If that isn't your question, update your question.

Comment: @Evan I showed you how to do that. WHERE? The delay part is what i am saying is not possible... or so it seems.

Comment: In the initial fiddle I posted. When you click the button, the element is immediately removed. After 2 seconds (the delay) a new element is added.

Comment: I updated the question with new code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EvanTrimboli I was finally able to come up with a solution.

```
function RemoveDiv() {
    $('#captcha').remove();
    $('#contain').delay(10000).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).append('<iframe id="captcha" class="captcha"
        src="/includes/captcha.php" style="style=border:0; overflow: hidden; 
        position: absolute; z-index: 100; width: 430px; height:75px;left: 20px; top: 20px; 
        border:none;"></iframe>');

        next();
    });
}
```